# Зачем в .gitignore оставляют папку .idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

Часто в репах на `GitHub` вижу файл .gitignore

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

почему не указывают `/.idea` а только

```
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
```

Answer (score 2):

Довольно часто вся команда разработки пользуется одним инструментом и с одним и тем же кодстайлом. Подключение нового разработчика с готовыми настройками намного удобнее, чем потом ловить косяки оформления на ревью кода.

Comment: а какие тогда канонические правила для этой папки?

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Answer (score 2):

Допустим есть несколько разработчиков, которые использую IDEA для разработки. Сама идея работает так что визаульные штуки типо открытых файлов, курсора и прочего она пишет в файлы в этой самой папке `.idea`. И если Первый разработчик зальёт эту папку в репозиторий, то у второго будет тоже самое что и у первого. Соответственно люди разные и по разному всё делают, может нужны разные файлы и т.д. Для этого и блокируют папку `.idea` - что бы не было, так сказать, конфликтов.

Answer (score 1):

обычно так ни кто не делает.
Смысла в этом особо нет

Comment: то есть это ошибка?

Comment: да просто безсмысленно это.  
workspace.xml - содержит только настройку окон IDE
libraries - хз зачем прописывать, т.к. это не значит что они устанавливаться будут

Comment: @PhilipPilipchuk, вот как раз наоборот - игнорить только локальные настройки смысл есть.